# Tmux start up script windows do not get split correctly

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh, tmux

I have written a startup script to create a new *tmux* session with three windows, with one of these windows being split vertically and horizontally:

```
#!/bin/bash
sV=awesome
tmux new -s "$sV" -n etc -d
tmux new-window -t "$sV":1 -n 'Email' "thunderbird"
tmux new-window -t "$sV":2 -n 'Firefox' "firefox"

tmux new-window -t "$sV":3 -n 'coding' "cd some-path"
tmux split-window -v
tmux split-window

tmux select-window -t "$sV":3
tmux -2 attach-session -t "$sV"
```

My Problem is that only two windows get created (Firefox and the split window) and the split window is only split once horizontally. The commands get executed correctly, except for the `cd` command, which - I guess - is due to the fact that the named window is not there.

I am pretty new to tmux, so I guess I made some really obvious beginner mistakes. Would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

> `tmux new-window -t "$sV":3 -n 'coding' "cd some-path"`

`cd` is a shell builtin and it does not stay around, when the shell exits the pane will close.

You can just use `-c` instead:

```
tmux neww -t "$sV":3 -n 'coding' -c some-path
```